# how to change text color on scroll in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm having some issue regarding changing text color on scroll in react.js i'm not sure what i'm missing here but simply put the H4 text in default is white in color and should change to black if on scroll

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import {Navbar, Container, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

const Navigation = () =>{
    const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);
    const [white, setColor] = useState(false);

    const changeBackground = () => {
        if(window.scrollY >= 80){
            setNavbar(true)
        }else{
            setNavbar(false)
        }
    }

    const changeColor = () => {
        if(window.scrollY >= 80){
            setColor(true)
        }else{
            setColor(false)
        }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll',changeBackground);
    window.addEventListener('black',changeColor);

    return(
        <Navbar className={navbar ? 'scroll' : 'navbar'} expand="lg">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><h4 className={white ? 'black' : 'white'}>Brand</h4></Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="#projects">Tab1</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#blog">Tab2</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.Link href="#contact">Tab3</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
};

export default Navigation;
```

Here's the css file

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-height:6vh;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.black {
    color: #000000;
}

.white {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.scroll {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

How can i be able to properly execute this? or am i really missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code as follows. If we registered the functions on every render, it will affect the memory leaking.
So I inserted the **appending event listener** into the **useEffect** without dependencies(it is the same case component Didmount and componentWillUnmount)

In my opinion, the most important updated part from above code the event **black** can't be understandable so I added the function scroll event.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Navigation.css';

const Navigation = () => {
  const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

  const changeBackground = () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 80) {
      setNavbar(true);
      setColor('black');
    } else {
      setNavbar(false);
      setColor('white');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground, true);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Navbar
      className={navbar ? 'scroll' : 'navbar'}
      expand='lg'
      style={{
        position: 'fixed',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      }}
    >
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href='#home'>
          <h4 className={color}>Brand</h4>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
        <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
          <Nav className='me-auto'>
            <Nav.Link href='#projects'>Tab1</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href='#blog'>Tab2</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        <Navbar.Collapse className='justify-content-end'>
          <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href='#contact'>Tab3</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

The screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5guv.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/13zHV.png

Comment: Very nice, i tweaked it a little bit, but you're the man. Thanks

Comment: i have a question tho how would you start with a white text as default? since the navbar is transparent at first but gradually turns white when scrolled down

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener that is supposed to change color is attached to the wrong event. It should be attached to `scroll` event.

```js
window.addEventListener('black',changeColor); // incorrect event name 'black'

// Change to 
window.addEventListener('scroll',changeColor);
```